# How to specify multiple && and || conditions in if statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has three blocks face-book, twitter and pinterest.
I added a condition to allow submitting the form only when one of the block is selected.
For that I did:

```
if ($("#fb").prop("checked") || $("#tw").prop("checked")||
  $("#pin").prop("checked")) {
    ...
    ...
}
if ($("#fb").prop("checked") || $("#tw").prop("checked")||
  $("#pin").prop("checked")) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now I want to add another condition where it will check inside the twitter block to check if the text field has less than 140 characters.
For that I added an and condition

```
if ($("#fb").prop("checked") || $("#tw").prop("checked") && $(#"tw_text").val().length <= 140||
  $("#pin").prop("checked")) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

But this has some faults like if the facebook is selected and tw_text has more than 140 characters then also the form gets submitted.

Please guide me to the correct way to add conditions to prevent submitting the form.

Comment: can you please edit the question and explain the exact logic (but do keep in the non-functioning code). Do feel free to use psuedo-code and plenty of parenthesis to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I used this way to resolve the issue.

```
if($("#fb").prop("checked") || $("#tw").prop("checked") || $("#pin").prop("checked")) { 
    if ($("#tw").prop("checked")) { 
        if($('#tw_text').val().length <= 140) { 
           ...submit form... 
        } 
        else { 
            .... show error for twitter text length.... 
        } 
    } 
    else { 
        ...submit form... 
    } 
} 
else { 
    ... show error message to select minimum one of the options between fb,tw and pinterest ... 
}
```

Comment: @brianlmerritt Thank you for the concern. I did solve the issue using this method.

Answer (score 4):

You need parentheses to group them (the [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of logical OR `||` is smaller than logical AND `&&`):

```
if ($("#fb").prop("checked") || 
    ($("#tw").prop("checked") && $(#"tw_text").val().length <= 140) ||
    $("#pin").prop("checked")) {
...
```

Comment: But if user selects fb and tw and no of twitter text's character is more than 140 , then also it will submit the form. i want to prevent this.

Comment: so you want only one (valid) selection?

Comment: No. i want user to select minimum one of the three and if he selects twitter he should have twitter text less than 140. If fb and twitter are selected together , it should also check for the no of characters and prevent submitting if condition gets false.

Comment: you answer is missleading, so if twitter and twitter length <140 and facebook then ...? yes or no?

Comment: Then it should allow submitting the form.

Comment: my proposal does it. it is `true` **if** either one of facebook **or** twitter **with** correct length **or** pinterest is `true`.

Comment: Sorry if i am unable to explain you, but this fails the condition when all three are selected (fb,tw and pin) and twitter length is greater than 140.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112120/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-developer).

Comment: Can you please update the question to correctly reflect the problem thanks @DEVELOPER

Comment: I don't think that is your job :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your description is that only for twitter you need a compulsory condition to be satisfied. Simply using brackets should help you here. Hope the following helps:
    `if ($("#fb").prop("checked") || ($("#tw").prop("checked") &&       $(#"tw_text").val().length <= 140) ||
  $("#pin").prop("checked")) {
    ...
    ...
    }`

Comment: But if user selects fb and tw and no of twitter text's character is more than 140 , then also it will submit the form. i want to prevent this.